# resource declaration not resolved into my WPF XAML View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

must be a silly one but I can't figure out what is wrong...

I do not manage to properly declare my converter class into my XAML WPF View:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="AFF00018.View.ControlReport"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="Report" Height="600" Width="850" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False"
        BorderBrush="#6593CF" BorderThickness="2" AllowDrop="False" ResizeMode="NoResize"
         xmlns:Converters ="clr-namespace:AFF00018.Tools.Converters"        
    >
    <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <Converters:Tray_Converter x:Key="Tray_Converter" />
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid >
...


 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding  IncorrectInserts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{x:Null}"
                      Margin="15" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="100"   RowHeight="50" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>

  <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.1666*" Header="Réf." 
              Binding="{Binding Tray, Converter={StaticResource Tray_Converter}}"  />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
...
    </Grid>
    </controls:MetroWindow>
```

My class is definitely defined into this NS:

```
 namespace AFF00018.Tools.Converters
    {
 [ValueConversion(typeof(Tray), typeof(string))]
        public class Tray_Converter : IValueConverter
        {
              ...
        }
    }
```

Compiler says that:
Tray_Converter does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace:AFF00018.Tools.Converters"
It stops displaying the displayer because of this error.

It still runs. The Convert method of the converter actually gets hit.
But its value parameter is always null although this is not the case in the database.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
xmlns:Converters ="clr-namespace:AFF00018.Tools.Converters"
```

to

```
xmlns:Converters="using:AFF00018.Tools.Converters"
```

and you should be good. I did notice there was space between `Converters` and `=` but probably just a typo

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. It actually makes the same results :(

Comment: Ive seen this before have you tried cleaning solution and doing a rebuild

Comment: Does not help :(.
Not sure if you read my edit, although compiler reports this error, it runs, hits the class Convert method but the 'value' argument is always null.

Comment: ok so converter is setup correctly but it cant determine `Tray`. Have you checked this properties value in the code (not database)?

Comment: Brillant!!
The code was lazily loading so all records were selected with a null Tray.
Thx for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Cool glad you got it sorted :)